# PHP Array overwriting values but need to add to array

Tags: php, arrays, overwrite

The array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.php
                    [1] => Title 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2.php
                    [1] => Title 2
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.php
                    [1] => Title 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4.php
                    [1] => Title 4
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.php
                    [1] => Title 5
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Trouble Shooting
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a.php
                    [1] => Title A
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Trouble Shooting
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b.php
                    [1] => Title B
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deprecated
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123.php
                    [1] => Title 123
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Admin Only
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => admin.php
                    [1] => Title Admin
                )

        )
)
```

What I need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.php
                    [1] => Title 1
                    [3] => 2.php
                    [4] => Title 2
                    [5] => 3.php
                    [6] => Title 3
                    [7] => 4.php
                    [8] => Title 4
                    [9] => 5.php
                    [10] => Title 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Trouble Shooting
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a.php
                    [1] => Title A
                    [3] => b.php
                    [4] => Title B
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deprecated
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123.php
                    [1] => Title 123
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Admin Only
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => admin.php
                    [1] => Title Admin
                )

        )
)
```

Whats happening

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Service Simulators
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5.php
                    [1] => Title 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Trouble Shooting
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b.php
                    [1] => Title B
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deprecated
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123.php
                    [1] => Title 123
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Admin Only
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => admin.php
                    [1] => Title Admin
                )

        )
)
```

What I'm trying, it's coming from a query result set

```
$tmp_arr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
   // $row[1] = groupname
   // $row[2] = pagename
   // $row[3] = pagetitle

   // Push to array
   $build_arr_items = array($row[2],$row[3]);

   array_push($tmp_arr, array($row[1], $build_arr_items)); // This builds the first example

   //$tmp_arr[$row[1]]=$build_arr_items; // this is the overwrite example
}
```

any thoughts, help in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I found something that works. I just reversed the Key Index relations

```
$tmp_arr[$row[2]]=$row[1];
$tmp_arr[$row[3]]=$row[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you married to that array structure? You might be better served by an array keyed by the group name ie:

```
Array(
    'Service Simulators' => array(
                              [0] => 1.php
                              [1] => Title 1
                              [3] => 2.php
                              )
      //etc...
      )
```

Because then you could code like so:

```
$tmp_arr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
     // $row[1] = groupname
     // $row[2] = pagename
     // $row[3] = pagetitle

      $tmp_arr[$row[1]][] = $row[2];
      $tmp_arr[$row[1]][] = $row[3];
}
```

This way also seems a bit less messy.

Comment: +1 very good approach. You can as well do it this way and transform it into your desired format, if you really need to.

Comment: And I actually think the inner array could be associative as well `$tmp_arr[$row[1]][$row[2]] = $row[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed pivotal's example to keep a similar structure to the op, but setting each by named key:

```
$tmp_arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    // $row[1] = groupname
    // $row[2] = pagename
    // $row[3] = pagetitle

    $tmp_arr[ $row[1] ] = array( $row[2], $row[3] );
}
/*
    Output
    array(
        "Group Name" => Array(
            Array(
                0 => "pagename"
                1 => "pagetitle"
            )
         )
    )
*/
```